# How to prevent automatic linebreaking when changing textsize in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a header for a website, currently I'm trying to have the homepage link be big, while having everything else be just abit smaller. However this automaticaly causes a line break. This is the current offending line:

```html
<h1 align="left"><a href="Russian Mockery-Home.html">A Mockery Of Russia - </a></h1><h2><a href="Russian Mockery-Poem.html">Poem - </a><a href="Russian Mockery-Military.html">Broken Military - </a><a href="Russian Mockery-WarCrime.html">Attempted War Crimes - </a></h2>
```

A quick google search told me that the `<nobr>` tag might fix this. Nope. That may be for a older version of HTML. Another person said that putting `width: 50%;` in the linked CSS H1 might solve the issue. That didn't either, and just messed up the spacing somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h1` and `h2` are block elements. have you tried with elements that are displayed inline? lets try with `span` since you're dealing with text. read more about [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) at mdn.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="h1">
    <a href="Russian Mockery-Home.html">A Mockery Of Russia - </a>
  </span>
  <span class="h2">
    <a href="Russian Mockery-Poem.html">Poem - </a>
    <a href="Russian Mockery-Military.html">Broken Military - </a>
    <a href="Russian Mockery-WarCrime.html">Attempted War Crimes - </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great! However, I did some google searching after your previous comment told me about the `span` tag, and I found the `<small>` tag, which perfectly does what I want, decreasing the fontsize by 1 step. H1 to H2, H2 to H3, etc.. Both of these work fine for anyone who encounters this post in the future!

Comment: `<small>` is great because it is also semantically fit. theoretically you could style any element to be `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` but that would be less predictable  for others